# Another series convergence question

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, divergent-series

Does this series converge?

$\displaystyle\sum\limits_{n=2}^\infty \frac{\sqrt{n+1}}{(2n^2-3n+1) (\ln n +(\ln n)^2)}$

Comment: What do you think?

Comment: I tried using the Cauchy Condensation Test, but the resultant expression doesn't seem helpful.

Comment: The terms of the series are all positive; all you need do is use the Comparison Test, after proving convergence of the series of terms $\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{\sqrt{n+1}}{2n^2 - 3n + 1}$

Comment: Ah, thank you, user_blahblah.

Comment: @Ryan: is this a problem created by you? It seems unusual for a book. (subjectively speaking)

Comment: It's from page 128 of David Brannan's A First Course in Mathematical Analysis (1st edition), an end-of-chapter optional exercise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Informally, for large $n$, $\sqrt{n+1}$ behaves like $n^{1/2}$, the quadratic in the denominator behaves like $2n^2$, giving a combined behaviour of $\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{1}{n^{3/2}}$, plenty good enough for convergence. And the $\log$ stuff at the bottom gives our series a minor (and unnecessary) boost towards convergence.

More formally, we can note that for $n\ge 3$, 
$$0 \lt \frac{\sqrt{n+1}}{(2n^2-3n+1)(\ln n+\ln^2 n)}\lt \frac{\sqrt{n+1}}{n^2-3n+1}$$
So if we can prove that $\sum_2^\infty \frac{\sqrt{n+1}}{n^2-3n+1}$ converges, it will follow by Comparison that our series converges.

Now note that $\sqrt{n+1}\le 2\sqrt{n}$, and that if $n \ge 6$, then $n^2-3n+1\ge \frac{1}{2}n^2$. It follows that for $n\ge 6$, we have
$$\frac{\sqrt{n+1}}{n^2-3n+1}\lt \frac{4}{n^{3/2}}.$$
Since $\sum_2^\infty \frac{1}{n^{3/2}}$ converges, the series $\sum_2^\infty \frac{\sqrt{n+1}}{n^2-3n+1}$ converges.

Answer (score 5):

Yes.${}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: Please provide your reasoning.

Comment: @Ryan One might well ask the same of you....

Comment: @JonasMeyer: this was a really fast answer! (+1):-)

Answer (score 2):

This one requires no tricks - look at the ratio of the numerator and denominator in the limit $n \to \infty.$ In fact, you can even throw out the $\ln n$ term.

Answer (score 0):

There is $n_0$ such that
$$\displaystyle\sum\limits_{n=2}^\infty \frac{\sqrt{n+1}}{(2n^2-3n+1) (\ln n +(\ln n)^2)}<\displaystyle\sum\limits_{n=n_0}^\infty \frac{\sqrt{n+1}}{(n+1)\cdot(\sqrt{n+1})^2}=\sum\limits_{n=n_0+1}^\infty \frac{1}{n\cdot\sqrt{n}}$$
Thus the series clearly converges.